# How to create multidirectional infinite/circular scrolling view like the HBO GO iPad App

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uikit, custom-controls

My question is essentially what it says in the title--I would like to create a scrolling view similar to the one that appears under the 'Home' tab of the HBO GO iPad application.

I have looked into circular/infinite UIScrollViews, but they only discuss infinite content in one direction (either horizontal OR vertical) and bring up many problems when scroll speed gets too high.  So my question is twofold:

A) Could they have created this scrolling view by subclassing UIScrollView?  If so, please do let me know how?

B) If not, does anyone have ideas as to a starting point for how they *could* have created it?  It runs very, very smoothly even at fast acceleration, and I'm trying to figure out how they created this.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you thought about setting up a 3x3 grid, all with the same content (maybe it could be a 2x2 if your content size is large enough) and simply shifting the views around based on the scrolling? Kind of like the photo logic in [this video by Apple](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2011/includes/advanced-scrollview-techniques.html#advanced-scrollview-techniques), but with both directions being handled? That's how I assume they're doing it.

Comment: mbm, thanks--I appreciate you pointing me in this direction. The video you linked me to seems like it will do what I want if I use it in both horizontal and vertical directions, but for the life of me I cannot find the sample code anywhere. Can you point me in that direction, and in the direction of the other Apple videos mentioned that explain the tiling?  If you could do that I think I'd be able to get this working.  And then if you'd repost as an answer, I'd be happy to accept :)

Comment: The sample is named [StreetScroller](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/StreetScroller/Introduction/Intro.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reposting to get answer ;-)

The sample is named [StreetScroller](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/StreetScroller/Introduction/Intro.html).

Referenced video is [here](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2011/includes/advanced-scrollview-techniques.html#advanced-scrollview-techniques).

I believe the successful technique will be to apply the techniques in the video in either a 2x2 or 3x3 grid and handle scrolling in both directions.

Comment: Thank you very much!  I think I've figured out the confusion I was having--is the solution you're suggesting to make one single UIView (in my case probably an 8x4 grid) which is made up of 8 across and 4 down of smaller views, and that each time I scroll, I create and add to the view another instance of the ENTIRE grid, not just however many of the smaller pieces of the grid are visible?

Comment: I would think you could do with less than that. It may or may not work seamlessly, but I would think you could use Apple's trick of resetting the `contentOffset` to keep "recentering" the view, but without the user knowing it.

Comment: Ah but see, for argument's sake let's say we have a 2x2 grid taking up the whole screen...I drag the scrollview down so that only half of the bottom two pictures are showing.  What appears at the top of the screen? I can't move the bottom images to the top of the screen, because then there would be empty space at the bottom. So in some fashion I am required to create at least two instances of my grid cells (more, when we start talking about simultaneous horizontal and vertical scrolling) to fill in the screen seamlessly. What would you suggest? (I really appreciate your help with this!!)

Comment: I think we're saying different things. :-) When I say 2 x 2 grid I mean four copies of your entire layout. I understand, or it seems like, your layout is a grid; something like 8 x 4. I'm talking about four of those. Does that make better sense?

Comment: Ahhh, yes.  I think we were saying the same thing but in different ways and getting signals crossed xD  Thanks!  I'm pretty sure this is the way to go.  Back at work today, so I'm going to try and get this functioning before the day is out.  As soon as I get it working I'll come back and accept your answer, I promise ^^  Thanks for all your help!! @mbm30075

Comment: Got it, thanks to your examples and help!  Thanks very much again!  I'm so happy it's working, haha. :) @mbm30075

Answer (score 1):

I have put together a library that provides an infinitely scrolling view in all directions. It allows you to very easily achieve the effect you’re looking for and much more. As the user scrolls around, the framework lays out the tiles and lets the delegate know so it can set up the tiles' presentations. This is indeed done by subclassing UIScrollView and as for performance, the framework introduces no lag: full 60 fps no matter how fast you scroll.

The framework with a sample app that displays Flickr images in an infinitely scrolling wall is here: https://github.com/vovagalchenko/scroll-for-days. Additionally, here's a video of the sample app in action: https://cloud.box.com/s/d6bgvlot175au5a3jeh5

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is an easy way to do it by sub classing UIScrollView

I have done something similar with a UIView and a custom gesture recognizer, moving views around nice they disappear off the side of the screen.

I hope this helps you.

Comment: Jason, can I have more information please?  Do you have perhaps a flow of the steps you took to achieve this, or some sample code?